# TableAdapter configuration wizard unexpected error c#

Tags: c#, query-builder, tableadapter

So, I have a DataSet1.xsd created with a wizard.
Right now, I am trying to configure its tableadapter to select a different column.

I go to dataset, rightclick on datatable -> configure, open the sql query builder, apply the change needed (uncheck one column, check another instead).

> *The 'execute query' preview returns expected result.*

But when I press 'Finish' to save, it throws an error messagebox:

> *An unexpected error has occurred. Error message: The object has been
>   deleted.*

Any ideas ?

Only found one post about similar issue for vs08.. I am using vs2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution would be simply deleting the current adapter, and creating a new one with same name.
Copy-paste the query, alter it, you can then save it.

The configure issue looks like it could be a bug that first appeared in vs08, it is reported and the ticket has been closed back in 2009, since it could not be reproduced.
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44089